# How to draw up this hierarchical diagram?(Or similar way)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I Would like to know how to draw this diagram or similar.
Thx.
[image]

I have started to use LaTeX just a few weeks to try pass a `.doc` to `.tex`, but I don't know how do this image. I tried use one exemple to do that, but I could not adjust the size and add dashed line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{trees} % this is to allow the fork right path


\title{Tikz}
\author{fernando_bcc }
\date{April 2014}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level.style={sibling distance=1mm}]
\tikzset{edge from parent/.style= 
            {thick, draw, edge from parent fork down},
         every tree node/.style=
            {draw,minimum width=0.8in,text width=1in,align=center,{sibling distance=1mm}}}


\Tree 
    [. Sistema 
        [.{Estáticos}
        ]
        [.{Dinâmicos}
            [.{Variante no tempo } ]
            [.{Invariante no tempo}
                [.{Linear} ]
                [.{Não Linear} 
                    [.{Estados contínuos} ]
                    [.{Estados discretos} 
                        [.{Dirigidos pelo tempo} ]
                        [.{Dirigidos por eventos} 
                            [.{Determinísticos} ]
                            [.{Não determinísticos}
                                [.{Tempo discretizado} ]
                                [.{Tempo contínuo} ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ] 
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). Which specific part are you having difficulty with?  There should be several example on this site to get you started.

Comment: Please post the code you've got so far so people have something to start with! Just posting an image is not really a reasonable question as it makes it harder to help and even to understand the context and question. All questions should include a complete small document demonstrating the issue or showing what efforts you've made so far. Without this, you have to hope the procrastinators take a liking to your question and want to while away some time!

Comment: Try having a check at [link](http://ftp.uniroma2.it/TeX/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), pages 364 on...

Comment: To draw the line, all you need to do is to place some names to designated nodes and use those names to draw the line. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One option using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest} 
for tree={
  edge path={
    \noexpand\path[line width=1.5pt,\forestoption{edge}]
      (\forestOve{\forestove{@parent}}{name}.parent anchor) -- +(0,-16pt) -|   
      (\forestove{name}.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
  },
  l sep=12pt,
  draw,
  fill=white,
  align=center,
  drop shadow
} 
[Sistemas
  [Dinámicos]
  [Estâticos
    [Variante no tempo]
    [Invariantes no tempo
      [Linear]
      [N\~ao linear
        [Estados contínuos]
        [Estados discretos,name=discretos
          [Dirigidos pelo tempo,name=pelotempo]
          [Dirigidos por eventos
            [Determinísticos]
            [N\~ao determinísiticos
              [Tempo discretizado]
              [Tempo contínuo,name=continuo]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
\draw[dashed,red]
 ([xshift=-4pt]pelotempo.north west|-continuo.south) --
 ([xshift=-4pt,yshift=4pt]pelotempo.north west) --
 ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=4pt]discretos.west|-pelotempo.north) --
 ([xshift=-2pt,yshift=8pt]discretos.north west) --
 ([xshift=20pt,yshift=8pt]discretos.north east) --
 ([xshift=35pt]continuo.south east);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @user1313455 You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept answers that you consider solved your problems by clicking the checkmark to their left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: Does the documentation include any examples with the branches like this? (i.e. like with the standard tikz `edge from parent fork down` from the `trees` library?) I looked but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: @cfr No; there's no examples like this one. I took the relevant code from page 90 (lines 1873-1878) Section **10.4.2 Declaring options**, where the code is documented.

Comment: Thanks. I've never looked at `forest` before and it wasn't obvious where that might be! I'll try to remember 'options' for next time!